# Open images from AUCTeX with your favourite image editor

Tags: emacs, auctex

Suppose I edit a LaTeX-file with AUCTeX and the point is on a `\includgraphics{myimage.jpg}` line. Is there a possibility in AUCTeX to open `myimage.jpg` with my favourite image editor, say `gimp` by just pressing a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Do any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of a general emacs question. What you really want is a way of linking from file-names in the buffer text to an external program. You may have to play with it to get it to work, but I'm guessing that [gimpedit.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/nxhtml/blob/master/util/gimpedit.el) would be able to do this.